# Sql conditional query parameters (include a parameter only when the corresponding form field is filled)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, forms, validation

I'm writing a php program using mssql where I have a long query with many parameters and a quite big database. How could I solve that a parameter in the query only gets included when the corresponding form field is filled?

example:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserdID='' AND Status='' AND ...
```

Lets say that this is an admin tool for seraching users but I only want to include those `AND parameter=''` sections where the corresponding form field has been filled.

I could check each form field and stich together the query but I feel like there is an easier and more elegant way.

Comment: create your query in PHP with dynamic WHere Clause, and add AND clause only when field has value otherwise not?

Comment: "check each form field and stitch together the query"  <-- this will actually produce the most performant sql, even if it looks clunky in your PHP.

Comment: If you want your query to include only "sections where the corresponding form field has been filled," then how else do you expect to do it with PHP other than "stitching together a query"?

Comment: Thanks for everyone who commented, it seems stiching together the query is the best solution. (i was originally looking for a way to maybe do it in the sql itself or some other magical way).

Answer (score 0):

Brother I hope you go with  bellow algorithm

1. Create a Globel Variable for condition.
2. Check first input that value is not blank, if not blank then put into globel variable .
3. So on with other fileds.
4. After All input check the globel varriable content only those condtion which user submited.

Sample Example.

```
var a="";
if(txtUser!="")
{
a = a==""?"username= ".txtUser:"username= ".txtUser;
}

if(txtCountry!="")
{
a = a==""?"country= ".txtCountry:a." and country= ".txtCountry;
}
```

a  variable for where condition